# How to show a specific character in an array of string or char from a different class

Tags: c++

Beginner in c++ and programming here. If this sounds stupid then you know why.
 I'm trying to compare a variable to a specific character in an array of string or char. It works, when I compare it to a . I want to use the "if" function, but are there any other way of doing it? C++

I tried doing   `if(variable == Obj.ArrayofString[0][1])` and `if(variable == b[0][0])` doesn't work

```
#include "DataBase.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string input;
string b[] = {"Lol","Fight"};

int main()
{
    DataBase Bo;

    cout << "Type a letter" << endl;
    cin >> input;

    if (input == Bo.Words[0]){
        cout << "Got one" << endl;
    }


    cout << Bo.Words[0][0];


    return 0;

}

**enter code here**
```

When I try to compare a specific variable to a specific character from a specific element in an array, I get an error. Plz help. Check the red line at the bottom in the "Build messages" tab

[no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::_cxxll::string {aka std::_cxll and some other stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1suy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are trying to compare a `string` to a `char`. These two are different types. For example, your input could contain multiple letters.

The solution is simple: Take the first character of your input string.

```
if (input[0] == Bo.Words[0][0]){
    cout << "Got one" << endl;
}
```

*I assume here that `Bo.Words[0]` is also of type `std::string`. Also, I refer to your linked code. In your posted code, you have `Bo.Words[0]` instead of `Bo.Words[0][0]`.*